# Read access violation при удалении объекта структуры

Tags: c++

Имеется такая структура:

```
struct account {
    string  login;
    string  pass;
    bool    admin;
};
```

И такая функция:

```
bool auth() {
    account user;
    account input;
    ifstream fin("users.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);

    if (fin.is_open()) {
        while (true) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "login: ";
            getline(cin, input.login);
            cout << "pass: ";
            getline(cin, input.pass);

            while (!fin.eof()) {
                fin.read((char*)&user, sizeof(user));

                if (input.login == user.login && input.pass == user.pass) {
                    fin.close();
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "hello, " << user.login << "\n" << endl;
                    cout << "press any key...";
                    _getwch();

                    return user.admin;
                }
            }
            system("cls");
            cout << "Incorrect login or password\n" << endl;
            cout << "press any key...";
            _getwch();

            fin.clear();
            fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "File is not avalible" << endl;
        abort();
    }
}
```

При завершении работы функции именно у объекта `user`, видимо, не получается удалиться, и вызывается исключение **read access violation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fin.read((char*)&user, sizeof(user));
```

Вот так - просто в память - можно считывать только то, что называется POD - plain old data. Тот же `string` - это сложный класс, в котором хранятся указатели на динамически выделенную память и т.п. вещи. Вы считали какой-то указатель, который когда-то - в другой программе, быть может - указывал в какое-то правильное, корректно выделенное место в памяти. А теперь куда он указывает?
Именно. Хрен знает куда.
Потому и получается хрен знает что, когда программа пытается корректно освободить память - непонятно какую, непонятно где.

Категорически нельзя так хранить серьезные вещи. Тот же `string`, если нужно бинарное хранение, лучше записать как целое число - количество символов, а потом сами символы. А затем, когда считываете, сначала считываете длину, готовите соответствующий буфер, читаете в него строку и собираете объект `string`.

Comment: + не забывам про архитектуру (размер типов), выравнивание и другие вещи, которые могут быть совсем не такими, как на читающей стороне.

Comment: Ну или просто заменить на массив чаров

Comment: Это пожалуйста :)

Comment: @lisovskey, в этом случае придётся либо отказаться от бинаргого формата и ограничивать длину строки. Либо всё равно хранить длину строки и выделять память под строковые элементы структуры динамически.

Comment: @PinkTux Почему же? Если объявить, скажем, `struct account {
    char  login[20];
    char  pass[20];
    bool    admin;
};`, то все будет нормально работать.

Comment: @Harry, и писать/читать её по `адресу/sizeof()`? Тогда см. мой первый комментарий.