# нарушение доступа для чтения с бинарным файлом

Tags: c++, файлы

```
using namespace std;
string Get_write(string login, ifstream &fb1)
{
User x;
string a;
fb1.open("data.dat",  ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
//fb1.seekg(sizeof(User) * 0, ios::beg);
fb1.read((char *)&x, sizeof(User));
while (!fb1.eof() || ((x.Get_NickName()) != login))
{
    fb1.read((char *)&x, sizeof(User));
}

//a = x.Get_Pass();
fb1.close();

return a;
}
bool Proverka_Logina(string login)
{
User x; bool tr = false;
fstream fb;
fb.open("data.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
do
{
    fb.read((char *)&x, sizeof(User));
    if (x.Get_NickName() == login)
    {
        tr = true;
    }
} while (!fb.eof());
fb.close();
if (tr = true)
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}


case 2:
    cout << "\nВведите логин пользователя: ";
    cin >> login;
    if (Proverka_Logina(login) == true)
    {
        ifstream fb1;
        password = Get_write(login,fb1);
    } 
    do
    {
    cout << "Введите пароль: ";
    cin >> password;
    } while (Klient.Get_Pass() != password);
    break;
default:
    break;

}

}
```

Здравствуйте, третий час сижу и не могу понять, выдает ошибку при выходе из функции Get_write, помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну нельзя читать/писать вот так -

```
fb1.read((char *)&x, sizeof(User));
```

что-то, кроме простейших структур! Вряд ли у вас `User` - plain old data (POD). Там же наверняка что-то есть не совсем фундаментальное :)

На фоне этого стандартная ошибка

```
while (!fb1.eof()
```

это уже и вовсе мелочи...

Comment: А как тогда нужно считывать? Просто я кроме примеров на структурах ничего не находил.

Comment: Зависит от конкретного вида `User`. Ну, вот пример - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/650110/195342 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/617451/195342

Comment: Даже если я поменяю операцию или на и у меня та же ошибка

Comment: При чем тут операция И или ИЛИ?!

Comment: Да свои заморочки, я теперь разобрался, спасибо за пример)

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый...

Comment: Harry,я посмотрел, у меня весь класс из string состоит, я так понимаю это тот самый POD, следовательно как структуру можно же записывать?

Comment: Из `string`, `char[]` или `char*`? Ну смотрите сами - `string` состоит из указателя на выделенную где-то память, каких-то полей. При такой записи вы просто записываете **указатель**, но не то, на что он указывает. Потом считываете - а там, куда указывает считанный указатель - строки нет и близко. Там вообще у вас доступа нет...

Comment: только string:)

Comment: Ну я же вам дал ссылки на 2 ответа, где описано и почему так нельзя, и как можно. `string` - это категорически не POD! POD - это, например, `struct Date { int year, month, day; };`.

Comment: Вон оно как, спасибо)